# Node Webkit - Executable Program Name

Tags: executable, node-webkit

My program I am running using the NodeWebkit is called app.exe. (The one where I combine the basic .exe with my app.nw file.)

How do I find the program name, ie the "app.exe", within the program itself using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it finally. It can be got from process.execPath.